# SSMS Having clause not returning result expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have query with a HAVING clause that's not giving the expected result.

The query is below:

```
SELECT COUNT(ClientProductID), SubCategoryName 
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure #
GROUP BY ClientProductID, SubCategoryName Having (PackSizeNum) > 5
```

And the error I get is below (the HAVING clause is included in the GROUP BY clause, so I don't understand why it would give this error?). Can anyone shed any light, please?

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 121
>   Column 'v_EnterpriseStructure.PackSizeNum' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: That answers part of it, but not all of it. I've added PackSizeNum to the GROUP BY clause, which gets rid of the error (thanks). However, the results I get look like this (below). Every result is '1' but it should return the number of products with a Pack Size that's greater than 5 in each SubCategory. Any other ideas? Thanks in advance. (No column name) SubCategoryName
1 DOGTREAT S.
1 STYLIN G.
1 CANNEDSOU P.

Comment: @Mr2017 the duplicate *is* the full answer. You *can't* use arbitrary columns in the `HAVING` clause. They have to be part of the GROUP BY clause. As for the results, are you sure `1` is the *wrong* value? How many `ClientProductID`s are there per `SubCategoryName` ? You'll have to provide sample data and the expected output for people to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` should not have a `ClientProductID` as you being called in aggregation `COUNT()` :

```
SELECT COUNT(ClientProductID), SubCategoryName 
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure #
GROUP BY SubCategoryName 
HAVING COUNT(PackSizeNum) > 5;
```

Comment: Great - thanks Yogesh. This answers my question. Thank you.